# How to Group on Pivoted Table with Dynamic Rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset like this

```
[student][datetime][dictionary][value]
[1234   ][datetime][1         ][a    ]
[1234   ][datetime][2         ][b    ]
```

I want to create a dataset like this

```
[student][1         ][2    ]
[1234   ][a         ][b    ]
```

I understand that SQL Server pivots are a way to accomplish this. I've written the below code to attempt to pivot the data however, it's naturally not grouped.

So my results end up like this:

```
[student][datetime][1         ][2    ]
[1234   ][datetime][null      ][b    ]
[1234   ][datetime][a         ][null ]
```

How can I best group these? I don't care about having the other source columns such as datetime in the final dataset, only the matrix of dictionaries and values

Thank you

```
DECLARE @columns AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @columns = substring((Select DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(dictionary)     FROM syuservalues FOR XML PATH ('')),2, 1000);

SELECT @sql =

'SELECT Pivoted.*
FROM syuservalues
PIVOT 
( MAX(value) 
  FOR dictionary IN( ' + @columns + ' )) as Pivoted where student =     327392'; ' Will eventually want it for all students

EXECUTE(@sql);
```

Comment: My answer here may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678403/sql-query-gather-data-based-on-date-range-possible-variable-number-of-column/28682459#28682459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `b` is brought to two rows because, you have added `[datetime]` column for pivot and the `[datetime]` value for `a` and `b` will be different.

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP([student] INT,[datetime] DATETIME,[dictionary] INT,[value] VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1234,'2015-02-01',1,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, '2015-02-01',2,'b'
```

Declare a variable to get columns for pivot dynamically

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CAST([dictionary] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']', 
                '[' + CAST([dictionary] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']')
               FROM    
               (
                    SELECT DISTINCT [dictionary]  
                    FROM #TEMP                     
                ) PV 
               ORDER BY CAST([dictionary] AS INT)
```

Now pivot it. I have written the logic inside.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '-- Your pivoted result is here
              SELECT * 
              FROM 
             (           
                -- Select data before pivot. We are not taking [datetime] column because 
                -- it will not bring ur expected result      
                SELECT student,[dictionary],value  
                FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 -- Value in each dynamic column
                 MIN(value)
                 -- Tell the columns to pivot
                 FOR [dictionary] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY student;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Please feel free to ask for any changes @M Quickel

Comment: I had to add a group by here and the aggregated columns as well but this solution worked well to improve performance and also allow me to exclude columns that were of type text that were getting pulled in a larger set. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem, you can just use an arbitrary aggregate function so that you get rid of the nulls. I usually use `max` because it can be used on both numeric and string data types.

```
select pivoted.student, [1] = max([1]), [2] = max([2])
from syuservalues
pivot(max(value) for dictionary in(...)) pivoted
group by pivoted.student
```

Comment: I needed dynamic columns so I created a secondary columns variable to generate the aggregates and it seemed to work as expected.